# Adsense converts all impressions to ZERO every 10-15 minutes!

Tags: google-adsense, impressions

On January 6, I received a email from Adsense that my Identity verification was successful.
But as of January 9 there was huge drop in my ad impression and as of then till now it just stuck to ZERO impression!(below screenshot).
[image]
I can see that as of January 14, **all my impressions convert to ZERO** every 10-15 minutes.
So at first, the impressions are being counted, but after 10-15 minutes all of them are gone!
Clicks also are not being counted at all.
I have verified my Identity and Address (PIN status: VERIFIED) and I have **no policy issue**.
The ads script are well-implemented on my site and I have enough traffic.
My site is approved and works normally.
The **ads are displaying correctly** and my account status is open.

I can't understand what the issue is.
Anyone can help, please?